# cant get a total of several inputs in Jquery

Tags: jquery

im having problems with making a total of all my inputs. when I echo the class in html it is just changing the variable and not making a sum of all my inputs.

```
 <script>$(document).ready(function(){
    var prijs = 0;
    var cas = 0;
    var voeding = 0;
$("input[name='behuizing']").click(function() {
        prijs -= cas
        cas = parseInt(this.id);
        prijs += cas;
        $('.test').html(prijs);
    });
    $("input[name='voeding']").click(function() {
        price -= voeding
        voeding = parseInt(this.id);
        price += voeding;
        $('.test2').html(price);})
;});
</script>

<body>
<p class="test"></p>
</body>
```

the class test needs to make a total of al the selected radiobuttons. 
these are my forms.

```
 <Form name ="form" Method ="Post" ACTION ="radiobutton.php">
    <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='behuizing' value= '1' id='25'>Sharkoon VS3-S red </br>
    <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='behuizing' value= '2' id='25'>Sharkoon VS3-S blue </br>
    <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='behuizing' value= '3' id='25'>Sharkoon VS3-S green </br>
```

Cooler Master G600 EU
        Cooler Master B700

Comment: Start by using _unique_ IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with @undefined in that you need unique IDs, because that's what IDs are for. If you need to group elements together, use classes.

But aside from that, I see two issues: you haven't defined `price` and you don't have the `test2` class that you reference in your second handler in your HTML.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/2HyJC/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <Form name ="form" Method ="Post" ACTION ="radiobutton.php">
            <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='behuizing' value= '1' data-price='25'>Sharkoon VS3-S red </br>
            <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='behuizing' value= '2' data-price='25'>Sharkoon VS3-S blue </br>
            <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='behuizing' value= '3' data-price='25'>Sharkoon VS3-S green </br>
            <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='voeding' value= '1' data-price='65'>Cooler Master G600 EU</br>
            <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='voeding' value= '2' data-price='70'>Cooler Master B700 </br>
    </Form>
    <p class="test"></p>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var b = 0,v = 0
$("input[name='behuizing'],input[name='voeding']").change(function() {
        b=$("input[name='behuizing']:checked");
        v=$("input[name='voeding']:checked");
        b=b.length==0?0:parseInt(b.attr('data-price'));
        v=v.length==0?0:parseInt(v.attr('data-price'));
        $('.test').html(b+v);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uE5Gf/3/